# Issue while updating mongodb document while using mongoosastic

Tags: node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch, mongoosastic

I am using mongoosastic to index documents into ElasticSearch. save(), remove() etc are working fine, but when I update() a document it is not being reindexed in elasticsearch. Could you please help me understand how to update a mongodb document so that mongoosastic automatically reindexes the updated document? Thanks a lot.

Here is the code snippet

```
Product.update({"_id" : {$in : productIDs}}, {l2Category : req.body.newL2CategoryName}, {multi : true}, function(errUpdatingProducts){
        if(errUpdatingProducts)
        console.log(errUpdatingProducts);
});
```

In the Product Schema, l2Category is indexed as String

```
l2Category: {
    type: String,
    es_indexed: true,
    es_type: 'string'
},
```

One way could be to load the data to the client from the mongodb server by using find() and update each document at the client and then save it back to the server by using save(). But it does not seem to be the smartest way.

Comment: mongoosastic works by implementing pre/post save middlewares of mongoose, which means it will try to index whenever _.save_ is called(or _.findByIdAndUpdate_). When you use _.update_ mongoose just directly calls mongodb so no middleware is called. [Refer this link](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html)

Comment: Thanks Varun. Although that logic is right, _.findByIdAndUpdate_ also does not seem to re-index the update. :(.

Comment: However, _.findById()_ and _.save()_ work when used together. It reindexes the information.

Comment: Correct, just found that since version 4.x.x mongoose has hooks for update, findOneAndUpdate etc as well, so perhaps these events also have to be implemented in mongoosastic.

Comment: @SamarthAgrawal see this answer i have same problem but i found the solution http://stackoverflow.com/q/33992359/4696809

Comment: @KevalBhatt Thanks a lot for sharing. This seems like the right way. Will try  tonight and get back soon.

Comment: @SamarthAgrawal have you tried with my answer

Comment: Hi @KevalBhatt, I tried the way you suggested (with upsert true and new true), it did update the data in mongodb server, but did not re-index the data in elasticsearch. I am dealing with an array here.. so I tried your way in various ways.. I tried a _forEach_ loop along with _.findOneAndUpdate({"id" : productID})_ and also normal _update{"id" : {$in : productIDs}}_ .. both updated the database.. but did not re-index the information in elasticsearch..

Comment: @SamarthAgrawal   can you post  your code what you did with schema

Comment: @KevalBhatt, Heres the code.. 

`l2Category: {
  type: String,
  es_indexed: true,
        es_type: 'string'
 },`

So, `var ProductSchema = new Schema({
      l2Category: {
  type: String,
  es_indexed: true,
        es_type: 'string'
 },
});`

I have an array of productIDs in category. Within each product I save the name of the category it belongs to as a string.. Whenever the category name is updated, I need to update the same in the products.. so that products are searchable based on category as well. Now I am trying to re-index l2Category whenever this info is updated.

Comment: @SamarthAgrawal so have you used ProductSchema.plugin(mongoosastic) post your code in fiddle or any where else you havent use mapping also

Comment: instead of writing code hear you have to use https://jsfiddle.net/ or plunker

Comment: Sure. Let me figure out jsfiddle.net and share the code there..

Comment: @SamarthAgrawal     see how to create schema http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/mt652L3m/1/

Comment: Heres my Schema.. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/sa2408/z1bqu0p0/)

Comment: @SamarthAgrawal analyzer mapping need indexed data it will search on mapping first you need to create mapping see this bug https://github.com/taterbase/mongoosastic/issues/22

Comment: see answer it will solve your problem

Comment: @KevalBhatt, Thanks a lot. Let me try this tonight and get back to you soon. 

Thanks again, Cheers,
Samarth

Answer (score 0):

Create mapping like this:

```
ProductSchema.plugin(mongoosastic);
Product = module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
Product.createMapping({ 
     "settings": {
     "number_of_shards": 1,
     "number_of_replicas": 0,
     "analysis": {
         "analyzer": {
             "autocomplete": {
                 "type": "custom",
                 "tokenizer": "standard",
                 "filter": ["standard", "lowercase", "stop", "kstem", "ngram"]
             }
         },
         "filter": {
             "ngram": {
                 "type": "ngram",
                 "min_gram": 2,
                 "max_gram": 15
             }
         }
     }
 },
 "mappings": {
     "Product": {
         "properties": {
              "yourschemaobject":...

         }
     }
 }
}, function(err, mapping) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('error creating mapping (you can safely ignore this)');
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log('mapping created!');
        console.log(mapping);
    }
});
```

In your mapping create object like my example. http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/mt652L3m/1/

When you done with mapping try to use this example for save and update https://stackoverflow.com/a/33992421/4696809