# mongoosastic findOneAndUpdate not indexing in elasticsearch

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, mongoosastic

> **Problem :** In my example if i user **schema.save** then it will indexed in elastic search
>
> but **problem starts** when i use **findOneAndUpdate** so it will not index in elastic even
>   if i insert (i.e save)

```
MovieSchema.findOneAndUpdate(query, reqObject, {
        upsert: true
    }, function(err, results) {
        if (err) {
            if (!update) {
                 var filePath = path.join(__dirname, "../../movie/images/uploads/") + reqObject.imageUrl;
                 fs.unlinkSync(filePath);
             }
            console.log(err)
            callback({
                RESULT_CODE: '-1',
                MESSAGE: 'System error. Please try again'
            });
        } else {

            callback({
                RESULT_CODE: '1',
                MESSAGE: 'Movie inserted'
            });

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fond the answer using **findOneAndUpdate**

**Example:**

> NOTE : pass **new : true** option **upsert: true** and it will work

**New** option will return updated or created object so internally mongoosastic work like if inserted object or updated object return then onty it will insert in elastic search index

```
MovieSchema.findOneAndUpdate(query, reqObject, {
        upsert: true,'new': true
    }, function(err, results) {
        if (err) {
            callback({
                RESULT_CODE: '-1',
                MESSAGE: 'System error. Please try again'
            });
        } else {

            callback({
                RESULT_CODE: '1',
                MESSAGE: 'Movie inserted'
            });

        }
    });
```

Comment: @gmaniac     i cant accept my own answer , only after  2 days i can accept my own answer :D